# VB.Net error to restore picture path using MySQL AES_ENCRYPT / AES_DECRYPT

Tags: mysql, vb.net

this my first question I hope post it in the right format.

I using MySQL AES_ENCRYPT / AES_DECRYPT from vb.Net to store and get users picture and files location. All works fine even the special spanish characters, except when I get the paths.

e.g

> saved path = C:\Users\User\Pictures and get = C:UsersUserPictures

I try with many codes also search on MySQL documentation without success still skip the backslash.

Please if can give me a orientation to fix this.

```
Dim MySQLQuery As String = "INSERT INTO `Agents` (`User_Name`, `User_Pic`) 
  VALUES (AES_ENCRYPT('" & txtUserName.Text & "', '" & MyPass & "'), 
    AES_ENCRYPT('" & txtUserPic.Text & "', '" & MyPass & "'"

MySQLQuery = "SELECT AES_DECRYPT(`User_Name`, '" & MyPass & "')
  AS UName, AES_DECRYPT(`User_Pic`, '" & MyPass & "') AS UPic 
  FROM `Agents`"

MsgBox(MySQLReader.GetString("UName") & vbCrLf &  
  MySQLReader.GetString("UPic")
```

Even I try to use other data types on MySQL as VARBINARY, VARCHAR, TINYTEXT with and without UTF8, LATIN1 and other and get allways the same, skip the backslash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `AES_ENCRYPT` the data entered is treated as binary string with as escape character the . So when you encrypt `\` and decrypt it again, you get an empty string as result. To preserver the `\`, you will have to pre-parse your string and replace the `\` with `\\`. This will preserve your `\` in the decrypt (however the decrypted string will show only one `\`).

Example:

```
 SELECT AES_DECRYPT(AES_ENCRYPT("s\ad",'test'),'test');
```

Returns: `sad` (so not a nice return).

```
 SELECT AES_DECRYPT(AES_ENCRYPT(REPLACE("s\ad","\","\\"),'test'),'test');
```

Returns: `s\ad`

Still very sad.

In the end: 100% mysql related, 0% vb related.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, although I know this site..
Regards about your help. TY :)